# Django - model mixin doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, django, django-models, mixins, django-2.1

In `PipedriveSync` model I use `GenericForeignKey` so any model can have `PipedriveSync` object related.

```
class PipedriveSync(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

And I use `GenericRelation` to be able to reference backwards this object. For example `user.pipedrivesyncs.all()`

Take a look at `User`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pipedrivesyncs = GenericRelation('pipedrive.PipedriveSync')
```

Since I have to specify the same `pipedrivesyncs` for many models, I decided to create a mixin for that (there are couple of methods there too but it doesn't matter now).

```
class PipedriveSyncRelatedMixin():
    pipedrivesyncs = GenericRelation('pipedrive.PipedriveSync')
```

And I use it this way

```
class User(PipedriveSyncRelatedMixin,AbstractUser):
    pass
```

The problem is that this `Mixin` doesn't work the way it works when I specify pipedrivesyncs manually.

Case of specifying `pipedrivesyncs` manually:

```
> u = User.objects.first()
> u.pipedrivesyncs.first()
> <PipedriveSync: PipedriveSync object (20)>
```

Case when using `Mixin`

```
> u = User.objects.first()
> u.pipedrivesyncs.first()
> AttributeError: 'GenericRelation' object has no attribute 'first'
```

Where is the difference and can I use `Mixin` for this purpose?

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations`?

Comment: Interesting. Did you make PipedriveSyncRelatedMixin an abstract model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It works with Mixin as abstract model. http://qaru.site/questions/821978/django-genericrelation-in-model-mixin Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixin has to be abstract and heritance should come from models.Model i think.

```
class PipedriveSyncRelatedMixin(models.Model):
    pipedrivesyncs = GenericRelation('pipedrive.PipedriveSync')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```